# Get maximum values in column with diferents foreign ids in Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to get the largest value from a column, but those values ​​correspond to two different foreign ids, so I want it to return the maximum number for each foreign id. I don't know If I have to use `max()`... At the moment I am just using `groupBy` with the two foreign ids.

Here the table in MySqlAdmin. I want to get the maximum `bid` for each `id_group` and `id_karatekas`:
[image]

And here is my code:

```
public function soldKarateka()
    {
        $response = array('code' => 400, 'error_msg' => []);
       self::getBidByKaratekaGroup($response);
       return response($response, $response['code']);
    }


    private function getBidByKaratekaGroup( & $response){
        $bidsPerKarateka = DB::table('bids')
            ->groupBy('id_group','id_karatekas')
           ->get();
             $response = array('code' => 200, 'Karatekas order by group' => $bidsPerKarateka);
    }
```

Comment: what do you mean get max values? there is only max value, do you mean order by the column

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try below code for find max value.
if your table name is `bids` then it will be ok otherwise change name as per your table name.

```
DB::table('bids')
->select([DB::raw('MAX(bids.bid) AS maxbid'), 'bids.id_group', 'bids.id_karatekas'])
->groupBy('bids.id_group', 'bids.id_karatekas')
->get()->toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the max function?

I think the following snippet will work

```
$data = DB::table('bids')
    ->select(DB::raw('MAX(bid) as bid'))
    ->groupBy('id_group', 'id_karatekas')->get();
```

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't work, just get maximum value, not all for each bid...

Comment: Yes! It is! Thank you so much!!